# editing image size with stylesheets

Tags: bootstrap-4, ruby-on-rails-5.2

I don't know how to create a class so that I can manipulate the image size in stylesheets, being inserted as a logo here:

```
<%= link_to image_tag("royal_lancers_badge.png"), root_path, class: "navbar-brand" %>
```

I'm using the bootstrap gem - the full code for the navbar is:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-dark">
  <div class="container">
    <%= link_to image_tag("royal_lancers_badge.png"), root_path, class: "navbar-brand" %>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item"><%= link_to "Home", root_path, class: "nav-link" %></li>
      <li class="nav-item"><%= link_to "About", about_path, class: "nav-link" %></li>
      <li class="nav-item"><%= link_to "Contact", contact_path, class: "nav-link" %></li>
      <% if user_signed_in? %>
      <li class="nav-item pull-md-right"><%= link_to "Log out", signout_path, method: :delete, class: "nav-link" %></li>
      <% else %>
       <li class="nav-item pull-md-right"><%= link_to "Sign up", signup_path, class: "nav-link btn btn-primary" %></li>
       <li class="nav-item pull-md-right"><%= link_to "Sign in", signin_path, class: "nav-link" %></li>
      <% end %>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

This was the key change which worked:

```
 <%= link_to image_tag("royal_lancers_badge.png", class: "logo"), root_path, class: "navbar-brand" %>
```